# Проверить наличие трех заглавных букв в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Объясните мне, почему этот код не работает и как это исправить:

```js
var str = "AaAA";
var r = new RegExp("[A-Z]{3,}");

if (r.test(str)) {
  console.log(":)");
} else {
  console.log(":(");
}
```

Я хочу проверить, что в строке есть ***три и более заглавные буквы***, но проверка проходит только, если они идут в строке подряд `AAA`, а если `AaAA`, то уже нет.

Comment: _почему этот код не работает_ - потому что в регулярке ясно указано, что буквы идут подряд.

Comment: @Air, внимательнее при редактировании, приписал одно слово делающее вопрос бессмысленным

Comment: @Grundy,  Ну автор и имел ввиду, что подряд....

Comment: @Air, наоборот же. с подряд у него проверка проходит.

Comment: @Grundy, ну да...  Ты прав...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данное выражение `[A-Z]{3,}` как раз и указывает на то, что 3 и более букв идут подряд.

Однако вместо `test` можно воспользоваться методом [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), который вернет все совпадения, и проверить количество найденных совпадений, например:

```js
var str = "AaAA";
var r = new RegExp("[A-Z]", 'g');

if (str.match(r).length >= 3) {
  console.log(":)");
} else {
  console.log(":(");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и в одну строчку:

```
(new RegExp('^.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*$')).test('BlaBlaBla');
```

```js
const pattern = new RegExp('^.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*$');

let actual = pattern.test('aaa');
console.assert(
  !actual,
  {msg: `'aaa' not pass`}
);

actual = pattern.test('aAbB.Z');
console.assert(
  actual,
  {msg: `'aAbB.Z' not pass`}
);

actual = pattern.test('aAbB.Za@');
console.assert(
  actual,
  {msg: `'aAbB.Z' not pass`}
);

actual = pattern.test('aAbB');
console.assert(
  !actual,
  {msg: `'aAbB' not pass`}
);

actual = pattern.test('BlaBlaBla');
console.assert(
  actual,
  {msg: `'BlaBlaBla' not pass`}
);
```